# Spring Oauth application not working in Microsoft Azure App

Tags: java, spring, azure

I created spring application implemented with oauth2.0 (authentication_code flow) and deployed into Azure App service. When I run it in my local machine its working properly and getting oauth token properly. But I deployed the same code in Azure App, its not working it showing ******.com redirected you too many times.

When I trace the traffic in "Network Sniffer", there is no cookie information in the response.

For reference i attached error screenshots.

[image: Too many redirect error]

[image: Network sniffer report]

Comment: Does my answer helps you? If so,you could mark it for answer.

Comment: Hey juunas, so what was the secret sauce to get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

Per my knowledge, `******.com redirected you too many times` error is different variation of error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`(also known as a redirect loop) in Google Chrome browser.

You could refer to below recommendations and things to check to fix the error.

***1.Delete cache and cookies on that specific site***

Cookies can sometimes contain faulty data in which could cause the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.Due to the fact that cookies retain your “logged in” status on sites and other settings, we recommend simply deleting the cookie(s) on the site that is having the problem. This way you won’t impact any of your other sessions or websites that you frequently visit.

***2.Determine nature of redirect loop***

The free [online Redirect Checker tool](http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php) can help provide some further analysis into what might be going on. This could also be done via cURL.

***3.Check your extensions by typing chrome://extensions***

Disable each of your extensions one by one while checking and refreshing your page, if the page starts working while a particular extension is disabled, that extension is faulty and you should delete it.

***4.Check Your HTTPS Settings***

If you have an SSL certificate on your domain host, you may deactivate it.

Hope it helps you.